# Replace " " with Space in a separated list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying get user input and seperate it letter by letter and also replace " " with "SPACE"

For this It Gives an Output Like

```
str[ 1 ]: H
str[ 2 ]: e
str[ 3 ]: l
str[ 4 ]: l
str[ 5 ]: o
str[ 6 ]:  
str[ 7 ]: W
str[ 8 ]: o
str[ 9 ]: r
str[ 10 ]: l
str[ 11 ]: d
```

How can i turn it into something like

```
str[ 1 ]: H
str[ 2 ]: e
str[ 3 ]: l
str[ 4 ]: l
str[ 5 ]: o
str[ 6 ]: SPACE
str[ 7 ]: W
str[ 8 ]: o
str[ 9 ]: r
str[ 10 ]: l
str[ 11 ]: d
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy. You can try matching the letter with a string containing space:

```
word= input("Enter a word ")
for index, letter in enumerate(word,1):
    if letter == " ":
        print("str[",index,"]:","SPACE")
    else: 
        print("str[",index,"]:",letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.strip` and if that results in an empty string, use `'SPACE'`

```
for index, letter in enumerate(word,1):
    print(f"str[ {index} ]: {letter.strip() or 'SPACE'}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, letter in enumerate(word,1):
    print('str[', index, ']:', letter.replace(' ', 'SPACE'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
def replaceall(word,string,replacement):
    word = list(word) #List the word for easy enumeration and print
    indices = [i for i,x in enumerate(word) if x == string] #Get all the index of the strings in the list
    for i in indices:
        word[i] = replacement #Assign replacement to string's position in the list
    return word #Return listed word because enumerate in words will print the letters of [replacement] out
a = replaceall('hello world',' ','SPACE') >>> ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'SPACE', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
for index,element in enumerate(a):
    print('str[',index,']:',element)
>>> str[ 0 ]: h
    str[ 1 ]: e
    str[ 2 ]: l
    str[ 3 ]: l
    str[ 4 ]: o
    str[ 5 ]: SPACE
    str[ 6 ]: w
    str[ 7 ]: o
    str[ 8 ]: r
    str[ 9 ]: l
    str[ 10 ]: d
```